# Como generar el cliente que muestre los datos de este service echo en NuSoap

Tags: c#, array, windows-forms, webservice, soap

Hola tengo el siguiente web service.

```
<?php
function ProcessMySoapObject() {
    $responce =[10];
    for ($i=0; $i <10 ; $i++) { 
        $object = (object) ['Nombre' => 'Nombre'.$i,'Descripcion' =>'Descripcion de la'.$i,'Precio' => $i];
        $responce[$i]=$object;
    }
}

require_once("lib/nusoap.php");
$namespace = "http://localhost/";
$server = new soap_server();
$server->configureWSDL("Productos");
$server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = $namespace;



$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'MySoapObject',
    'complexType',
    'struct',
    'all',
    '',
    array(
        'Nombre' => array('name'=>'Nombre','type'=>'xsd:string'),
        'Descripcion' => array('name'=>'Descripcion','type'=>'xsd:string'),
        'Precio' => array('name'=>'Precio','type'=>'xsd:int'),
    )
);


$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'MySoapObjectArray',
    'complexType',
    'array',
    '',
    'SOAP-ENC:Array',
    array(),
    array(array('ref'=>'SOAP-ENC:arrayType','wsdl:arrayType'=>'tns:MySoapObject[]')),
    'tns:MySoapObject'
);
$server->register(
    'ProcessMySoapObject',
    array(),
    array('return'=>'tns:MySoapObjectArray'),
    $namespace,
    false,
    'rpc',
    false,
    'Processes an array of MySoapObjects and returns one of them');

$POST_DATA = isset($GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']) ? $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'] : '';
$server->service($POST_DATA);                
exit();
?>
```

En la función he creado un ciclo for simulando que es el while que posteriormente sacara la información de la base de datos, y generara el array de objetos.
Todo esto esta bien, según todo lo que he investigado aunque no estoy seguro.

El array que se genera en el for es el siguiente:

```
[{"Nombre":"Nombre0","Descripcion":"Descripcion de la0","Precio":0},{"Nombre":"Nombre1","Descripcion":"Descripcion de la1","Precio":1},{"Nombre":"Nombre2","Descripcion":"Descripcion de la2","Precio":2},{"Nombre":"Nombre3","Descripcion":"Descripcion de la3","Precio":3},{"Nombre":"Nombre4","Descripcion":"Descripcion de la4","Precio":4},{"Nombre":"Nombre5","Descripcion":"Descripcion de la5","Precio":5},{"Nombre":"Nombre6","Descripcion":"Descripcion de la6","Precio":6},{"Nombre":"Nombre7","Descripcion":"Descripcion de la7","Precio":7},{"Nombre":"Nombre8","Descripcion":"Descripcion de la8","Precio":8},{"Nombre":"Nombre9","Descripcion":"Descripcion de la9","Precio":9}]
```

Ahora lo que quiero es diseñar el cliente en una aplicación de C#(form) que muestre los datos del array que estoy enviando por medio de nusoap. Este es el código del botón en la aplicación de C# con la que estoy probando.
Al agregar la referencia del web service a VisualStudio le coloque el nombre de "getProductos"

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getProductos.Productos s = new getProductos.Productos();
        getProductos.MySoapObject[] web = s.ProcessMySoapObject();

        MessageBox.Show(web[5].Nombre);
        MessageBox.Show(web[5].Descripcion);
        MessageBox.Show(web[5].Precio.toString());

    }
```

En este caso quiero sacar como ejemplo el Nombre, Descripción y Precio del objeto que esta en la posición 5 del array, sin embargo esto me manda un NullReferenceExeption y un InvalidOperationExeption. Me podrían asesorar para saber que es lo que estoy construyendo mal o como puedo sacar los datos de mi array.

De antemano muchas gracias.